# Taylor Diagrams by Group in R (openair)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a taylor diagram to show agreement between observations and model output. The openair package lets you differentiate by a group, which I would like to do for each site.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
TaylorDiagram(month_join, obs = "temp", mod = "temp_surf", group = "dataset_id", normalise = TRUE, cex = 1)
```

The observation variable is temp, model variable is temp_surf, and site that I want to differentiate by different groups, is dataset_id.

When I do this, though there are 17 different datasets, they are binned into four groups. I can't find any help online about this. The [function documentation](https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/reference/TaylorDiagram.html) says that for the group argument, "The total number of models compared will be equal to the number of unique values of group". I have 17 unique values in the group but they are automatically binned into 4.

[Taylor diagram with 4 groups instead of 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tncn.png)

[Edit: first 20 rows of data from month_join]

```
# A tibble: 20 × 14
# Groups:   dataset_id [2]
   dataset_id month temp_surf temp_mid temp_bot ph_surf ph_mid ph_bot do_surf do_mid do_bot  temp     ph    do
        <dbl> <ord>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1          3 1          13.4    13.3     13.2     8.01   7.99   7.97    244.   232.  220.   13.3   8.00   NaN
 2          3 2          13.3    13.2     13.0     8.01   7.98   7.96    245.   232.  218.   12.5   7.99   NaN
 3          3 3          12.9    12.7     12.5     7.97   7.94   7.91    233.   216.  199.   12.7   8.04   NaN
 4          3 4          12.6    12.4     12.2     7.93   7.91   7.89    223.   207.  190.  NaN   NaN      NaN
 5          3 5          12.9    12.7     12.4     7.93   7.91   7.89    223.   208.  193.  NaN   NaN      NaN
 6          3 6          13.5    13.2     12.9     7.94   7.92   7.90    226.   212.  198.   15.1   8.04   NaN
 7          3 7          14.3    13.9     13.5     7.97   7.95   7.94    236.   224.  212.   16.0   8.09   NaN
 8          3 8          14.4    14.1     13.8     7.98   7.97   7.95    238.   228.  217.   16.6   8.06   NaN
 9          3 9          14.8    14.5     14.1     8.00   7.99   7.97    244.   235.  227.   16.7   8.05   NaN
10          3 10         14.8    14.4     14.1     8.00   7.98   7.96    243.   233.  222.   16.2   8.05   NaN
11          3 11         14.3    14.0     13.7     7.99   7.96   7.94    237.   224.  211.   15.5   8.05   NaN
12          3 12         13.6    13.4     13.3     7.99   7.97   7.94    237.   225.  213.   14.4   8.05   NaN
13          6 1          14.3     9.48     4.70    8.07   7.84   7.62    261.   143.   24.7  13.6 NaN      NaN
14          6 2          14.2     9.42     4.68    8.07   7.84   7.62    264.   144.   24.4  13.5 NaN      NaN
15          6 3          14.5     9.61     4.67    8.07   7.84   7.61    266.   145.   24.2  14.0 NaN      NaN
16          6 4          15.0     9.86     4.68    8.06   7.84   7.61    264.   144.   24.0  14.3 NaN      NaN
17          6 5          16.0    10.4      4.68    8.05   7.83   7.61    262.   143.   24.0  16.4 NaN      NaN
18          6 6          17.3    11.0      4.68    8.04   7.83   7.61    257.   141.   23.9  17.6 NaN      NaN
19          6 7          18.8    11.7      4.71    8.03   7.82   7.61    251.   138.   24.2  19.3 NaN      NaN
20          6 8          19.2    12.0      4.76    8.03   7.82   7.61    248.   136.   24.7  NA    NA       NA
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(month_join)`?

Comment: I added a picture of the first few rows. It's an extremely long output when I use that ^^.

Comment: You could also show first 20 values using `head(dput(month_join),20)`.

Comment: Just updated the post